# dsPIC33EP256MC506 Uart TRMT not empty on interrupt

Tags: c, interrupt, uart, dspic

So I'm using the dsPIC33EP256MC506 and one of its UART for communication (9600,8,N,2). I need to get an interrupt when the Tx shift register is empty (TRMT = 1). By setting the UTXSEL bits to:

```
USTAbits.UTXISEL0 = 1;
USTAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0;
```

According to the data sheet UxSTA bit 15,13 UTXISEL[1:0]: = 01

```
11 = Reserved; do not use
10 = Interrupt when a character is transferred to the Transmit Shift Register (TSR) and as a result,
     the transmit buffer becomes empty.  
01 = Interrupt when the last character is shifted out of the Transmit Shift Register; all transmit
     operations are completed.  
00 = Interrupt when a character is transferred to the Transmit Shift Register (this implies there
     is at least one character open in the transmit buffer).
```

I know it says "...when the last character **is** shifted out..." which implies that the shift register isn't empty. On the other hand it also says "...**all transmit operations** are completed." which implies that the shift register should be empty.

However when the interrupt trig, the FIFO is empty and the TRMT = 0. So there is still a shift operation in progress.

```
TRMT: Transmit Shift Register Empty bit (read-only)
1 = Transmit Shift Register is empty and transmit buffer is empty (the last transmission has completed)
0 = Transmit Shift Register is not empty, a transmission is in progress or queued
```

On my Oscilloscope it looks like the interrupt is triggered somewhere among the stop bits.

I fail to see a practical difference between mode 10 and 01, both gives interrupt when there is data in the shift register.
Can some one explain/confirm if this is yet another Microchip bug or what the practical difference is between mode 10 and 01.

What I really need is to know when the last stop bit has left the shift register.

**MYSTERY SOLVED**
It is a silicon bug and it's mentioned in the errata.

> When using UTXISEL<1:0> = 01 (interrupt when last character is shifted
> out of the Transmit Shift Register) and the final character is being
> shifted out through the Transmit Shift Register (TSR), the Transmit
> (TX) interrupt may occur before the final bit is shifted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can consider it as a two-byte buffer.

The first byte is the "transmit buffer", which software can write directly to (when it is empty). The second byte is the shift register, which reads bytes from the "transmit buffer" and shifts them onto the wire.

`10` mode tells you the transmit buffer is now empty (and you can write something else into it) since a byte just got moved into the shift register.

`01` mode tells you when the shift register got emptied, i.e. the entire byte is now on the wire.

You can get an interrupt while the stop bit is being driven on the wire, because the stop bit is not part of the data in the shift register. All the data has been shifted out. The stop bit is "meta-data" as far as the MCU is concerned.

It feels like I just re-stated what you said in different words. But it makes sense to me, so not sure which part has confused you.

Comment: Yes, you rephrased what I just said :) But you also confirmed that the stop bits are not a part of the shift register data, so now it makes more sense to me too. However, shouldn't TRMT = 1 in mode 01 since the all bits has been shifted out?

Comment: Yes, I see your point, there is a contradiction. As you hinted, could be a silicon bug. Have you checked the errata?

Comment: But in fact it is a 5 byte buffer - there is a 4 level FIFO.

Comment: Yep, it's in the errata (when I finally found it) and they suggest the same work around I'm already using ;). This silicon bug has been there since at least 2014!

Comment: @pmacfarlane TRMT refers to the shift register according to the datasheet,.

Comment: @MaxKielland  - nasty;  I took a look at the errata and the suggested  workaround is shocking.  To suggest you busy-wait polling TRMT in an _interrupt_ should be unacceptable - at 9600 you could be spinning for 104us.  A better work around is to use mode 10b - the use cases for 01b are fewer (as noted in my answer).  Why do you need to know the shift register is empty?

Answer (score 0):

> I know it says "...when the last character is shifted out..." which implies that the shift register isn't empty. On the other hand it also says "...all transmit operations are completed." which implies that the shift register should be empty.

It seems this is a comprehension issue.  What makes you think that *"when the last character **is** shifted out"* implies the register is not empty?  It means *exactly* that - you even noted that with your oscilloscope.

> However when the interrupt trig, the FIFO is empty and the TRMT = 0. So there is still a shift operation in progress.

That is true on mode 10 only.

> I fail to see a practical difference between mode 10 and 01, both gives interrupt when there is data in the shift register.
> In mode 01 the interrupt occurs when teh shift register is empty. In mode 10 it occurs then the FIFO is empty

You would use use mode 10b to indicate FIFO empty and allow you to load the buffer to stream data without inter-character gaps.

You might use mode 01b to indicate all data has been transmitted before disabling the UART or entering a low power mode or issuing a software reset for example.  Or if you needed precise timing/synchronisation between character output and some other I/O event - for example you might be communicating with some device with a chip-select control that needs to be held up until completion.

In most cases you would want to use mode 10b, load the FIFO until `UTXBF`, then repeat on a mode 10b interrupt.

Comment: The errata confirmed that the interrupt may trigger to early, before the shift register is empty. "...the Transmit (TX) interrupt may occur before the final bit is shifted out"

Comment: @MaxKielland yes, spotted that comment, and commented on it.  Does it matter - what are you doing that you need to know the last bit has been transmitted?

Comment: I have to flip a RS485 half duplex transceiver after the last stop bit. So I need to know when all bits has been shifted out.

Comment: Understood.  That is a valid reason.  The workaround is a poor solution though for real-time systems, being an interrupt it would affect the scheduling of all task threads and lower priority interrupts.  I would suggest signalling a thread (like a deferred interrupt handler) to do the TRMT polling, then you can assign it a suitable priority and ensure deterministic scheduling.  Whatever thread performs the transceiver switch perhaps could do the polling?